# How can I export two lists of strings into two columns in a csv file without getting separated

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, export-to-csv

I have two lists `reviews_text` (which contains all the reviews) and `review_label` (which tells if the review is `Positive` or `Negative`). I need to export them to csv file with `reviews_text` and `reviews_label` as two columns.

I tried the following codes and I am unable to solve it.

```
np.savetxt('reviews.csv', [p for p in zip(review_text, review_label)], delimiter=',', fmt='%s', encoding="utf-8")
```

After saving them as csv file I want the `review_text` in a single column, but it is getting saved in a different column

When I open the csv file on Excel, I am getting something like this

> The output looks like this

```
         A       ,       B       ,       C       ,       D       ,       E

1 Very rustic...   off Knick...    salad           potatoes were..  Negative

2 Went here...     a crepe...      Negative

3 Huge fan of..    hot choc...     good place..    Positive
```

> But I want the out put to look like this

```
                   A                                     ,     B      

1 Very rustic place. Mismatched furniture,off Knick...      Negative

2 Went here for coffee, a crepe and salad but bad p...      Negative

3 Huge fan of their meatball, hot chocolate, good p...      Positive
```

I think the reviews after each `,` is getting separated and going to a new column. Is there anyway to solve it? Thanks

EDIT:

The output of `reviews_text` looks like something like this. Hope this helps in troubleshooting the problem in any way.

Output:

'Too expensive for what they had... i had an egg benedict plate called la drolet but it had a weird side soup with a desert that I dont personally like. I dont think i will go back there again....',
 "Very rustic place. Mismatched furniture, off Knick knacks. Would make a great Instagram photo place. Lots of variety on the menu. I had their brunch. Which comes with eggs, salad, potatoes, soup and dessert. Well worth the price. I was stuffed, actually couldn't finish the potatoes. Friendly service. Would definitely visit again.",
 'I highly recommend Au Festin de Babette for their brunch. Their selection of brunches is different than most other places. The one I usually go for includes a hot drink, a soup, a gratin dauphinois, two eggs Benedict, and a chocolate mousse. All of the items are excellent, especially the gratin dauphinois. This meal is usually very satisfying and cost less than $20 which is reasonable for good brunches in Montreal. The interior is very cute and feels homie and the service is usually good.',
...]

Comment: Look at np.array([p for p ...]).  That's what's being saved, one row/column at a tine.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it's because of the ",", change the delimiter in your code to something else. You could also encode "," in your review dataset and decode it later on.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I couldn't solve the problem as I tried changing the delimiter by using `\t` instead of `,` but the text would go to the next row now. I have edited the post and added the output of `reviews_text`. Hope that helps in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a small portion of data you are using if you want efficient answers. Let's assume you have this kind of situation:

```
review_text = ['Very rustic place. Mismatched furniture,off Knick', 'Went here for coffee, a crepe and salad but bad p...', 'Huge fan of their meatball, hot chocolate, good p... ']  
review_label = ["Negative", "Negative", "Positive"]
```

I see two problems on your code: one is that nasty list comprehension on a zip object and the other is the delimiter itself.

A quick fix to convert the data is the following:

```
import numpy as np  
np.savetxt('reviews.csv', np.asarray([review_text, review_label]).T, delimiter='\t', fmt='%s', encoding="utf-8")
```

It is worth noting that you have to select **only a tab** in the import tool of excel when opening the file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I couldn't solve the problem as after  using `\t` instead of `,` the text would go to the next row now. I have edited the post and added the output of `reviews_text`. Hope that helps in anyway.

Comment: I have added some input so that you can reproduce the example.